# Best practice when displaying inline HTML elements next to a h1 element?

Tags: html, css, block, html-heading

I have a webpage that displays the name of a "product", with edit/delete links next to it on the same line. Example:

**Product 1** (Edit | Delete)

I want the product name to have a large font size, and the edit/delete buttons to have regular font size (i.e. same as paragraphs and whatnot). And I want them to appear inline, like the example above. I'm just wondering what HTML/CSS I should utilise in order to achieve this.

If I use a h1 element for the product name, it pushes the edit/delete links to the next line because h1 is a block element. So I could override h1 in my CSS and make `display: inline`, but messing with the natural appearance of h1 seems like something that would be against best practices (?).

The other option is to simply not use a h1 element at all and use a couple of inline divs or spans. But not using a h1 element for the top-level header of a webpage seems like something that would go against best practices too... It would also require me to explicitly set the font sizes, meaning I can't use the default font sizes of h1 and p elements, which I use throughout the rest of the website.

What's the best approach in this situation? I know it's sort of a simple/trivial question, but it would be nice to know anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wrapper `div` for the `h1` and floating it might help you.

Is this what you are looking for? : http://jsfiddle.net/Pt2BZ/

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, those links don't belong in your `<h1>`. One way would be to float the heading, something like this:

```
​<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="tools"> <!-- perhaps use an unordered list here and not div -->
    <a href="#">Edit</a>
    <a href="#">Delete</a> <!-- use a form with POST to delete instead -->
</div>
```

```
h1 { float:left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JeuXt/

There's no universal best practice or method for the display part (the CSS), but you *do* want to keep your HTML clean and have everything semantically correct.

Comment: Why is my syntax highlighting all messed up?

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use the oft-neglected `display: run-in;` style. This will cause the `h1` to "run in" to the immediately adjacent block-level element.

**NOTE** - Browser-support for this rule may still be a bit spotty, so I would be sure to test it before use in a production environment.

HTML

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<div class="links">
    ( <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a> )
</div>​
```

CSS

```
h1 {     
    display: run-in;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bgmwh/)

Answer (score -1):

Personally I'd just use `<span></span>` tags with a CSS class against them instead of heading tags to make a custom type of heading. You'll have more flexibility that way as heading tags exhibit their own default behaviour and you may find yourself in a situation where any alterations you've made to the heading tag styling starts to impact other parts of your site going forward.

Edit: Here's a link to W3C's thoughts on the use of the `<H1>` tag: [link](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Use_h1_for_Title)

Comment: The issue with this once again is semantics. Heading should be marked up as `HX`.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend using the `<h1>` tag and wrapping the elements you want to make smaller in a `<span>`. Then set a class on the span and target it with CSS like:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Product 1 <span class="foo">(Edit | Delete)​​​​​</span></h1>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
​.foo {
    font-size: 10px;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HEhHc/)**

Comment: This will make (Edit | Delete) a part of the `<h1>`, and that is not a good practice.

Comment: @j08691: This would make your heading read as `Product 1 (Edit | Delete)​​​​​`. For starters, think screen readers - "Edit/Delete" is not part of the heading and should not be in the h1 tag.

Comment: @j08691 It's semantics. The `h1` element's purpose is to contain the header for the page you're currently viewing. `(Edit | Delete)` is probably not part of the page title, and therefore should not be in the `h1`

Comment: @jackwanders - I know about semantics. However based on the code the OP is using, this is a perfectly viable solution.

Comment: practically, yes, it's viable. But I was responding to your question on why it's not "good practice". What works and what's right are not always one and the same.