# How to display a h1 element with an inline element next to it and a p element below it?

Tags: html, css, block, html-heading

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303124/best-practice-when-displaying-inline-html-elements-next-to-a-h1-element) earlier about the best way to put edit/delete links inline with a h1 element. I was able to achieve this with the answers given, but I now have additional requirements where I need to display a paragraph below the h1 and edit/delete links.

So far, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="product-header">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Product 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="admin">
      (<a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>)
  </div>
  <p class="description">Product 1 is a cool product</p>
</div>
```

I'd like it to look like the following:

> **Product 1** (Edit | Delete)
>  *Product 1 is a cool product*
>
> ...rest of page content

But I'm not sure what CSS to use to achieve this! Everything I do seems to put the description paragraph on the same line as the title, like so:

> **Product 1** (Edit | Delete)*Product 1 is a cool product*
>
> ...rest of page content

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDQLZ/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add `clear:both` in **.product-header** class but you really need to add `clear:both` in **.product-header .description** class like given below:

```
.product-header .description {
    clear:both;
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/ngKwe/2/)

**Additional Notes:**

The [**clear**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear) CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `clear:both` to `.description`:

http://jsfiddle.net/kDQLZ/3/

Answer (score 1):

***[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kDQLZ/3/)***

Hi now clear your **p tag class** `clear left`

as like this

```
.product-header .description {
 clear:left;   
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kDQLZ/3/)***